# How to use set-based statement instead of cursor for converting 1 table to two, keeping relations

Tags: sql-server, cursors, relations

I'm relatively new to databases and currently working with SQL. I am doing a conversion for a customer. This conversion points to local files on a filesystem. In the old database there simply was a table containing file details and relations of that document to other entities. In our new standard file details and relation between files and other entities are seperated into 2 different tables. Let's call them "file" and "objectfile". For example, manual as a file. "file" will contain filename, upload date etc. "objectfile" will contain file-id and for example id of a phone or a task.

I have to convert the old to the new. Currently I am using a cursor but there is a lot of debate on cursors. A while loop was slower and 2 insert-into statement with a while-loop linking the two records together was slower than both other options. My search for set-based processing has also shown me that a LOT of time can be saved using set based approach. My cursor works as follows:

1. Get all rows of old table
2. For each entry get auto-increment key with
   a SP (we use our own system for auto-increment) for table "file" and
   "objectfile".
3. First insert a "file" entry containing some of the
   columns from the old table and the new file ID from the custom SP.
4. Then insert an "objectfile" entry containing some of the columns
   from the old table, the new objectfile ID from the custom SP ánd the
   file ID used in the previous statement.

Now the file and objectfile entries are related. I have looked into a set-based approach with "insert into" statements but I just can't figure out how to get the relations correct, if possible at all. I've found several links, for example about the output clause:

What I would want is something like the following (simplified compared to original database model):

```
insert into dba.File (FileCreateDate, FileLocation, FileFileName)
OUTPUT dba.File.FileId, (select GetDate(), PFilePhoneId from dba.PhoneFile)
INTO dba.ObjectFile (ObjFileFileId, ObjFileCreateDate, ObjFilePhoneId)
select PFileDate,PFileLoc, PFileName from dba.PhoneFile
```

But a subquery is not allowed in the output clause...What other way can I make this quicker? Currently a cursor takes around 30 minutes to complete 88000 rows, I'm curious to how much time-saving can be had.

The cursor (simplified as a lot of columns are involved):

```
DECLARE @PhoneFile_ID varchar(15)

DECLARE ObjFile_CURSOR CURSOR
FOR
SELECT PhoneFileId
FROM dba.PhoneFile

OPEN ObjFile_CURSOR

FETCH NEXT FROM ObjFile_CURSOR INTO @PhoneFile_ID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @FileId   NVARCHAR(12);
    EXECUTE dba.applspGetAutoIncValue FileId, @FileId OUTPUT;

    DECLARE @ObjFileId   NVARCHAR(12);
    EXECUTE dba.applspGetAutoIncValue ObjFileId, @ObjFileId OUTPUT;

    insert into dba.File (FileCreateDate, FileLocation, FileFileName)
    select PFileDate,PFileLoc, PFileName from dba.PhoneFile where PhoneFileId = @PhoneFile_ID

    insert into dba.ObjectFile (ObjFileId, ObjFileFileId, ObjFileCreateDate, ObjFilePhoneId)
    select @ObjFileId, @FileId, GetDate(), PFilePhoneId from dba.PhoneFile where PhoneFileId = @PhoneFile_ID


FETCH NEXT FROM ObjDoc_CURSOR INTO @PhoneFile_ID -- Once the work is done we fetch the next result

END

CLOSE ObjFile_CURSOR  
DEALLOCATE ObjFile_CURSOR
```

An example:
**PhoneFile table**

- PFileId - 1
- PFileName - 'manual.pdf'
- PFileLoc - '../Manual/'
- PFileDate - '2015-09-16 07:43:00.567'
- PFilePhoneId - '9463'

Should go into:
**File table**

- FileId - 00001
- FileCreateDate - '2015-09-16 07:43:00.567'
- FileName - 'manual.pdf'
- FileLoc - '../Manual/'

**ObjectFile table**

- ObjFileId - 00000001
- ObjFileFileId - 00001
- ObjFileCreateDate - '2016-01-13 13:19:00.000'
- ObjFilePhoneId - 9463

Comment: Can you post the code for your cursor to give us more of an idea?

Comment: I just added the cursor. Slightly simplified and names altered to keep it anonymous ;)

Comment: It would also be great if you provided sample data of the one table (and the wanted outpuy split into the 2 tables).

Comment: Added some sample data.

Comment: Is it possible to change the stored procedure dba.applspGetAutoIncValue to a function?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not. I can however update the value for every table. I'm not a developer but a consultant that implements our software at customers. We have set boundaries, within those boundaries we can modify. SP's are way outside those boundaries.